# C# WebClient: Illegal Character in link

Tags: c#, winforms, web, hyperlink, download

[SOLUTION]

> I passed the url into the path argument and the path into the url argument. Silly me

[/SOLUTION]

I want to make a updater program and so i have to download some File's (.zip) from dropbox. I have a download Methode in a .dll which a wrote myself, Shouldn't be a problem just wanted to Mention, Now when I call this Methode with a Link from a string array. I get:

[image]

Now the Error Message is German so I will translate it for you: "Exception while making a WebClient Request".

I can give some more information on the Error the Exact Error is:

"There is an Illegal character in the Download string"

I tried another link from dropbox.

> **Works:** `https://www.dropbox.com/s/n82iqqf1vmfrfhr/Base.zip?dl=1`
>
> **Doesn't Work:** `https://www.dropbox.com/s/dd146f85trixobv/update1.zip?dl=1`
>
> **Both links come from the same array...**

Which works just fine. So i don't know what the Illegal Character is...

[image]

The String array is generated using File.ReadAllLines() which reads a file with 3 links in it.

The File looks exactly like that:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/n82iqqf1vmfrfhr/Base.zip?dl=1
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dd146f85trixobv/update1.zip?dl=1
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xcmat8x8qlijxsn/update2.zip?dl=1
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe there's a `\r\n` or something like that in the link? Could you please check that?

Comment: The link is: https: //www.dropbox.com/s/dd146f85trixobv/update1.zip?dl=1 so there is **/s/d** in the link, but this doesn't explain the error since https: //www.dropbox.com/s/n82iqqf1vmfrfhr/Base.zip?dl=1 works just fine and has the same stuff in it.

Comment: The `/s/d` isn't problematic :) But you, said that you're reading the links from a file. Maybe there's an illegal character in that respective line of your source file.

Comment: The Files looks exactly like I showed in the section of my question. There is nothing in it except the links themselves. As far as I can see they are getting read correctly since in the first picture when you look at the first blue bracket the link is the exact same as in the File so it is getting read correct.

Comment: Could the error also be that the path is incorrect ?

Comment: You you add the complete exception text incl. stacktrace? Even if it's german ;)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Qol.png

Comment: Well you could try to uses backslashes instead of slashes in the `link` variable --> `C:\ProgramData\.....`. The `++` in the path could be a problem, too.

Comment: What is the Path value used for each of your Urls? Because the problem is not what is coming from dropbox, the problem is the file where you want to store the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what I am seeing in the picture number 1 , you have set path instead of link ! 
Your code is :

```
webClient.DownloadFile(path,link);
```

But the correct code is :

```
webClient.DownloadFile(link,path);
```

So Use the code below :

```
WebClient wb = new WebClient();
var link = new Uri("https://www.dropbox.com/s/dd146f85trixobv/update1.zip?dl=1")
wb.DownloadFile(link, @path);
```

Comment: Your right, I can't believe I didn't find that. :D But it makes Perfect sense since i download from the other link in a different method and there i had it the right way...